# deprovision users immediately instead of 30 days soft delete

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

**I have to deprovision users immediately  from azure AD instead of 30 days soft delete, any fix on this issue.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bypass the soft-delete mechanism by manually permanently deleting the users as stated in this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-restore#permanently-delete-a-user).

Basically, you can do this from the `Deleted users` blade of `Active Directory` in Azure Portal. You need to be `User Administrator`, `Global Administrator` or `Partner Tier1/2 Support`.

Comment: how about deleting/deprovisioning  them on app side IMMEDIATELY asap instead of  30 days  soft delete or any commands which can work on it ?

Comment: You cannot do it in one action, the soft-delete mechanism cannot be avoided. You could automate the deletion of deleted users by scheduling calls of Powershell commands ```Get-MsolUser -ReturnDeletedUsers``` and ```Remove-MsolUser``` accordingly with your needs.

Comment: thanks  for the  above answer , any other ways for deprovision on app side asap   need to do it immediately